# Eigen initialize from Matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I am currently working with Eigen in c++ and there is a few things about initialization that I couldn't find answers for.

Is it possible to initialize a Dynamic matrix using another dynamic matrix of the same size:

```
MyClass::MyClass(Eigen::Matrix<T, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen Dynamic> sourceMatrix)
{
    Eigen::Matrix<T, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen Dynamic> destMatrix(sourceMatrix)
}
```

The above seems to compile but my project is currently filled with other compile errors so I can't test it and I would like to be sure what it will do before using it. Will this make `destMatrix` a deep copy of `sourceMatrix` ? Or a shallow copy?

Is it any different than doing:

```
MyClass::MyClass(Eigen::Matrix<T, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen Dynamic> sourceMatrix)
{
    Eigen::Matrix<T, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen Dynamic> destMatrix(sourceMatrix.data())
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will do a deep copy, also `sourceMatrix` should probably be declared as a const reference. If you want a shallow copy, then you have to request for it explicitly using, e.g., a `Ref` object:

```
Ref<MatrixXd> dest(source);
```

See the documentation of `Eigen::Ref` for more details and examples.